# How do you quantify the flesh of "fish" that is used as food

Tags: quantifiers

I think we can say:

> I see two fish in the water.

Since it is a countable noun when it refers to:

> An animal that lives in water, and uses its fins and tail to swim

But both [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/fish) and [ldoceonline.com](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/fish) say it becomes an uncountable noun when the intended meaning of fish is:

> The flesh of fish as food

Therefore, I think saying this would make no sense:

> Can I have two fish for dinner?

So how do we quantify the fish used as food in English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Fish' can be used non-countably when referring to the food generically, so you can say e.g. 'I like fish with potatoes', 'we will have fish for supper', 'fish is cheaper in places near the sea'. Also, 'fish' is both the singular and most commonly used **plural** form of 'fish' as a countable noun, so you can also say 'can I have two fish please?'.

[What is the plural form of fish?](https://socratic.org/questions/what-is-the-plural-form-of-fish)